# Setting up Bootstrap Forms with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to get Bootstrap Forms working with my Python Flask Web-app but I am having difficulty getting it to work the way I want it to.

It is currently set up so that when a user signs up their details are stored in the database using SQLAlchemy and SQLite3. It currently doesn't seem to do that.

Originally I had the code setup using flask_bootstrap but I would prefer to use local bootstrap files instead which I would have located in the static folder.

I have included the original files I have been working from which are the original app.py and original signup.html. I have also included the new files I have been trying to create which are the new app.py and new signup.htm to help with the reproduction of this app. Thanks in advance!

### Original app.py File

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm 
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Email, Length
from flask_sqlalchemy  import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Thisissupposedtobesecret!'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////Users/Joanna/Desktop/login2/database.db'
Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('username', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)])
    remember = BooleanField('remember me')

class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('email', validators=[InputRequired(), Email(message='Invalid email'), Length(max=50)])
    username = StringField('username', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)])

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

        return '<h1>Invalid username or password</h1>'
        #return '<h1>' + form.username.data + ' ' + form.password.data + '</h1>'

    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    form = RegisterForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data, method='sha256')
        new_user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

        return '<h1>New user has been created!</h1>'
        #return '<h1>' + form.username.data + ' ' + form.email.data + ' ' + form.password.data + '</h1>'

    return render_template('signup.html', form=form)

@app.route('/dashboard')
@login_required
def dashboard():
    return render_template('dashboard.html', name=current_user.username)

@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

### New app.py File

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm 
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Email, Length
from flask_sqlalchemy  import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Thisissupposedtobesecret!'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////Users/Joanna/Desktop/login2/database.db'
Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('username', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)])
    remember = BooleanField('remember me')

class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('email', validators=[InputRequired(), Email(message='Invalid email'), Length(max=50)])
    username = StringField('username', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)])

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

        return '<h1>Invalid username or password</h1>'
        #return '<h1>' + form.username.data + ' ' + form.password.data + '</h1>'

    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    form = RegisterForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data, method='sha256')
        new_user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

        return '<h1>New user has been created!</h1>'
        #return '<h1>' + form.username.data + ' ' + form.email.data + ' ' + form.password.data + '</h1>'

    return render_template('signup.html', form=form)

@app.route('/dashboard')
@login_required
def dashboard():
    return render_template('dashboard.html', name=current_user.username)

@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

### Original signup.html Template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}
Sign Up
{% endblock %}

{% block styles %}
{{super()}}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('.static', filename='signin.css')}}">
{% endblock %}

{% block body_content %}
<div class="container">

  <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="/signup">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign Up</h2>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.username) }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.email) }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.password) }}
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
  </form>

</div> <!-- /container -->
{% endblock %}
```

### New signup.html Template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
Sign Up
{% endblock %}

<!-- Banner Image Content Begins -->
{% block img_content %}
    <div class="img_cont bg_img">
        <h1 class="banner">Sign Up</h1>
    </div>
{% endblock %}}
<!-- Banner Image Content Ends -->

{% block body_content %}
<div class="container">

<form method="POST" action="/signup">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username">{{ form.username }}</input>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">  
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">{{ form.email }}</input>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">{{ form.password }}</input>
    </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
</form>

</div> <!-- /container -->


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing `{{ form.csrf_token }}` inside your form in **signup.html**  :

```
<form method="POST" action="/signup">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <div class="form-group">
```

---

In order to detect what is going wrong, you could add `print(form.errors)` in the function `def signup():` to see it in the console, or even return it to the template for the user.

(the template is a bit strange with the double `input` rendered on screen, maybe take a look at this [doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/wtforms/))

---

**EDIT:**

The form already renders the input tags depending on the type of field, you only need to call the form's fields in your template. (I just added a small loop to render the form errors on validation)

```
<div class="container">

<form method="POST" action="/signup">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <div class="form-group">
       {{ form.username }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.email }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.password }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
    </form>

    {% for field, err in errors %}
      <div>{{field}} : {{err|join(', ')}}</div>
    {% endfor %}

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

To make the errors loop work, just change the return statement for the template in `def signup():`

```
return render_template('signup_bug.html', form=form, errors=form.errors.items())
```

Now if you want to define placeholders or other attributes, you can pass them inside a special parameter: `render_kw`

```
class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('email', 
                        validators=[InputRequired(), Email(message='Invalid email'), Length(max=50)], 
                        render_kw={"placeholder": "Enter Email", "type":"email"})
    username = StringField('username', 
                           validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)], 
                           render_kw={"placeholder": "Enter Username", "type":"username"})
    password = PasswordField('password', 
                             validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)], 
                             render_kw={"placeholder": "Enter Password", "type":"password"})
```

Comment: ok i have just edited the question with a bit more detail and what the code originally was and what it currently is. I'm new to flask so not sure how everything works. If you can help that would be great thanks

Comment: what do you need to fix first ? the database storage seems to work fine if you fix the template with `{{ form.csrf_token }}`

Comment: ok how to do i fix the template so that it doesn't appear with two input boxes for each? the {{ form.csrf_token }} fixes the database storage thanks.

Comment: i add some code in the answer, i hope this is helping

Comment: Thanks that helps so much :)

Comment: When the errors display they look like "username : [u'This field is required.']" the code i have looks like this                                              
 <div class="errors">
       {% for field, err in errors %}
        <p>{{field}} : {{err}}</p>
       {% endfor %}
      </div>                                                                                                                         How do i get it to display without the [u'] around it?

Comment: try with `<p>{{field}} : {{err|join(', ')}}</p>`, it will join all messages given for each field with a comma